# Order a query result by a numeric meta key even if it does not exist, but put the posts with meta key first

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, meta-query

I want to order a **WP Query** result by a numeric meta value in PHP.

To achieve this, I am doing as follows:

```
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'orden_en_categ', 
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'orden_en_categ', 
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
    )
) );
$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
$query->set('order', 'ASC');
```

Where the meta key is called `orden_en_categ`.

**And what is the problem?**

This query setting is displaying posts in the following order:

1. Post **without** meta
2. Post **without** meta
3. Post with meta and low values
4. Post with meta and higher values
5. ...

I want the posts without meta appear after the posts with meta, as follows:

1. Post with meta and low values
2. Post with meta and higher values
3. Post **without** meta
4. Post **without** meta
5. ...

Where the order of the posts **without** meta does not matter.

**The default meta solution:**

I know I could add a default meta to all posts with a value of something like 999 and this would work. But, there must be an alternative way, without having to add those sticky meta values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, just to clarify, in a normal situation without the specific order requirements, and assuming you are doing this on `pre_get_posts` hook, you would just do as follows:

```php
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {
    // only perform for a given query
    // do your checks and return early
    if (! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->is_home()) {
        return;
    }

    $query->set('meta_key', 'orden_en_categ');
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
});
```

There is no need to set a meta query at all.

Then, to achieve an ascending order with nulls last, there are differents approaches. Assuming your data is numeric, you could use a minus operator and order descending as follows:

```php
add_filter('posts_orderby', function ($orderby, $query) {
    global $wpdb;

    // only perform for a given query
    // do your checks and return early
    if (! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->is_home()) {
        return $orderby;
    }

    return "-{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value DESC";
}, 2, 10);
```

A more generic solution for alphanumeric values could be:

```php
add_filter('posts_orderby', function ($orderby, $query) {
    global $wpdb;

    // return early...

    return "{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value IS NULL, {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value ASC";
}, 2, 10);
```

`IS NULL` returns 1 for null values and 0 for not null. In ascending order, 0 (not nulls) will come first. Then we order by the value itself in ascending order too.

Last thing, when using the `posts_orderby` filter, you don't need these 2 lines anymore:

```php
$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
$query->set('order', 'ASC');
```

**Edit**: the original solution didn't take in consideration non existing meta values. Remove `meta_key`, `meta_query`, `orderby` and `order` query vars from `pre_get_posts` and filter the query as follows.

```php
add_filter('posts_clauses', function ($clauses, $query) {
    global $wpdb;

    if (!$query->is_main_query() || !$query->is_home()) {
        return $clauses;
    }

    $meta_key = 'orden_en_categ';

    $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '$meta_key')";
    $clauses['where'] .= " AND ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '$meta_key' OR {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id IS NULL)";
    $clauses['groupby'] = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";
    $clauses['orderby'] = "-{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value+0 DESC";

    return $clauses;
}, 2, 10);
```

Almost a full custom query but can't figure out a better approach. Hope it helps.

The resulting query will be something like:

```sql
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta
   ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'orden_en_categ')
WHERE 1=1
   AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
   AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
   AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'orden_en_categ' OR wp_postmeta.post_id IS NULL)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY -wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I tried your solution but it's not showing the posts that don't have the meta_key.

Comment: Maybe the reason is this: `{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value IS NULL`. It's not that they are NULL, it's that they don't exist at all.

Comment: I missed that case. I already got a working solution but let me come back to you in a while since it's a little cumbersome and I'd like to improve my answer and provide an elegant solution.

Comment: You are an elegant person. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Edited the original answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: ¡Perfecto, thanks a lot!